# Python - matplotlib: find intersection of lineplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, intersection

I have a probably simple question, that keeps me going already for quiet a while.  Is there a simple way to return the intersection of two plotted (non-analytical) datasets in python matplotlib ?

For elaboration, I have something like this:

```
x=[1.4,2.1,3,5.9,8,9,23]
y=[2.3,3.1,1,3.9,8,9,11]
x1=[1,2,3,4,6,8,9]
y1=[4,12,7,1,6.3,8.5,12]
plot(x1,y1,'k-',x,y,'b-')
```

The data in this example is totaly arbitrary. I would now like to know if there is a simple build in function that I keep missing, that returns me the precise intersections between the two plots.

Hope I made myself clear, and also that I didnt miss something totaly obvious...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We could use `scipy.interpolate.PiecewisePolynomial` to create functions which are defined by your piecewise-linear data.

```
p1=interpolate.PiecewisePolynomial(x1,y1[:,np.newaxis])
p2=interpolate.PiecewisePolynomial(x2,y2[:,np.newaxis])
```

We could then take the difference of these two functions,

```
def pdiff(x):
    return p1(x)-p2(x)
```

and use [optimize.fsolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html#scipy-optimize-fsolve) to find the roots of `pdiff`:

```
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import numpy as np

x1=np.array([1.4,2.1,3,5.9,8,9,23])
y1=np.array([2.3,3.1,1,3.9,8,9,11])
x2=np.array([1,2,3,4,6,8,9])
y2=np.array([4,12,7,1,6.3,8.5,12])    

p1=interpolate.PiecewisePolynomial(x1,y1[:,np.newaxis])
p2=interpolate.PiecewisePolynomial(x2,y2[:,np.newaxis])

def pdiff(x):
    return p1(x)-p2(x)

xs=np.r_[x1,x2]
xs.sort()
x_min=xs.min()
x_max=xs.max()
x_mid=xs[:-1]+np.diff(xs)/2
roots=set()
for val in x_mid:
    root,infodict,ier,mesg = optimize.fsolve(pdiff,val,full_output=True)
    # ier==1 indicates a root has been found
    if ier==1 and x_min<root<x_max:
        roots.add(root[0])
roots=list(roots)        
print(np.column_stack((roots,p1(roots),p2(roots))))
```

yields

```
[[ 3.85714286  1.85714286  1.85714286]
 [ 4.60606061  2.60606061  2.60606061]]
```

The first column is the x-value, the second column is the y-value of the first PiecewisePolynomial evaluated at `x`, and the third column is the y-value for the second PiecewisePolynomial.

Comment: thank you very much for your time! although not as simple as I hoped for, this will certainly do in resolving my problems :)

Comment: @unutbu Please can you check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200428/how-to-divide-2d-plane-into-mesh-grid-in-python/45203700?noredirect=1#comment77420650_45203700  and suggest me something

Answer (score 1):

**Parametric solution**

If the sequences {x1,y1} and {x2,y2} define arbitrary (x,y) curves, rather than y(x) curves, we need a parametric approach to finding intersections. Since it's not entirely obvious how to do so, and because @unutbu's solution uses a defunct interpolator in SciPy, I thought it might be useful to revisit this question.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1_array = np.array([1,2,3,4,6,8,9])
y1_array = np.array([4,12,7,1,6.3,8.5,12])
x2_array = np.array([1.4,2.1,3,5.9,8,9,23])
y2_array = np.array([2.3,3.1,1,3.9,8,9,11])

s1_array = np.linspace(0,1,num=len(x1_array))
s2_array = np.linspace(0,1,num=len(x2_array))

# Arguments given to interp1d:
#  - extrapolate: to make sure we don't get a fatal value error when fsolve searches
#                 beyond the bounds of [0,1]
#  - copy: use refs to the arrays
#  - assume_sorted: because s_array ('x') increases monotonically across [0,1]
kwargs_ = dict(fill_value='extrapolate', copy=False, assume_sorted=True)
x1_interp = interp1d(s1_array,x1_array, **kwargs_)
y1_interp = interp1d(s1_array,y1_array, **kwargs_)
x2_interp = interp1d(s2_array,x2_array, **kwargs_)
y2_interp = interp1d(s2_array,y2_array, **kwargs_)
xydiff_lambda = lambda s12: (np.abs(x1_interp(s12[0])-x2_interp(s12[1])),
                             np.abs(y1_interp(s12[0])-y2_interp(s12[1])))

s12_intercept, _, ier, mesg \
    = fsolve(xydiff_lambda, [0.5, 0.3], full_output=True) 

xy1_intercept = x1_interp(s12_intercept[0]),y1_interp(s12_intercept[0])
xy2_intercept = x2_interp(s12_intercept[1]),y2_interp(s12_intercept[1])

plt.plot(x1_interp(s1_array),y1_interp(s1_array),'b.', ls='-', label='x1 data')
plt.plot(x2_interp(s2_array),y2_interp(s2_array),'r.', ls='-', label='x2 data')
if s12_intercept[0]>0 and s12_intercept[0]<1:
    plt.plot(*xy1_intercept,'bo', ms=12, label='x1 intercept')
    plt.plot(*xy2_intercept,'ro', ms=8, label='x2 intercept')
plt.legend()

print('intercept @ s1={}, s2={}\n'.format(s12_intercept[0],s12_intercept[1]), 
      'intercept @ xy1={}\n'.format(np.array(xy1_intercept)), 
      'intercept @ xy2={}\n'.format(np.array(xy2_intercept)), 
      'fsolve apparent success? {}: "{}"\n'.format(ier==1,mesg,), 
      'is intercept really good? {}\n'.format(s12_intercept[0]>=0 and s12_intercept[0]<=1 
      and s12_intercept[1]>=0 and s12_intercept[1]<=1 
      and np.isclose(0,norm(xydiff_lambda(s12_intercept)))) )
```

which returns, for this particular choice of initial guess [0.5,0.3]:

```
intercept @ s1=0.4761904761904762, s2=0.3825944170771757
intercept @ xy1=[3.85714286 1.85714286]
intercept @ xy2=[3.85714286 1.85714286]
fsolve apparent success? True: "The solution converged."
is intercept really good? True
```

This method only finds one intersection: we would need to iterate over several initial guesses (as @unutbu's code does), check their veracity, and eliminate duplicates using `np.close`. Note that `fsolve` may falsely indicate successful detection of an intersection in the return value `ier`, which is why the extra checking is done here.

Here's the plot for this solution:
[image: Example solution]

Answer (score 0):

can use [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225991/15893581):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x1 = np.array([1.4,2.1,3,5.9,8,9,23], dtype=float)
y1 = np.array([2.3,3.1,1,3.9,8,9,11], dtype=float)
x2 = np.array([1,2,3,4,6,8,9], dtype=float)
y2 = np.array([4,12,7,1,6.3,8.5,12], dtype=float)

# plt.plot(x1,y1,'ko-',x2,y2,'bo-')
# plt.show()

##https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225385/intersection-point-between-2d-arrays
def intersection(X1, X2):
    x = np.union1d(X1[0], X2[0])
    y1 = np.interp(x, X1[0], X1[1])
    y2 = np.interp(x, X2[0], X2[1])
    dy = y1 - y2

    ind = (dy[:-1] * dy[1:] < 0).nonzero()[0]
    x1, x2 = x[ind], x[ind+1]
    dy1, dy2 = dy[ind], dy[ind+1]
    y11, y12 = y1[ind], y1[ind+1]
    y21, y22 = y2[ind], y2[ind+1]

    x_int = x1 - (x2 - x1) * dy1 / (dy2 - dy1)
    y_int = y11 + (y12 - y11) * (x_int - x1) / (x2 - x1)
    return x_int, y_int

res = intersection([x1, y1], [x2, y2])
print(res)
if len(res)!=0:
    t=np.array(res); print(t)
    d= pd.DataFrame(t.T, columns= ['x', 'y']); print(d)

plt.plot(x1,y1,'ko-',x2,y2,'bo-', d.x, d.y, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

[image]