# Finding the point of intersection of two line graphs drawn in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to find the point of intersection of two line graphs in matplotlib?

Consider the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()


ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[20,100,50,120,55,240,50,25],color='lightblue',linewidth=3)
ax.plot([3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [25,35,14,67,88,44,120], color='darkgreen', marker='^')
```

I tried referring to [Python - matplotlib: find intersection of lineplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094374/python-matplotlib-find-intersection-of-lineplots) , but the method seems to be too intricate - it involves advanced maths concepts like Piecewise Polynomial Interpolation, can understand what the API is doing from docs but don't really get the concept behind it, if anyone could provide an easier solution or explain what is going on in the Piecewise polynomial solution, it would be of great help.

Comment: Are you looking for this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766692/intersection-of-two-graphs-in-python-find-the-x-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an ugly solution (an improved version is at the bottom). After plotting, we know that two line graphs make a cross at the range of `(6, 7)`

[image]

Now, we plot this cross point with the following source code,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
y1 = [20,100,50,120,55,240,50,25]
x2 = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y2 = [25,35,14,67,88,44,120]

ax.plot(x1, y1, color='lightblue',linewidth=3)
ax.plot(x2, y2, color='darkgreen', marker='^')


# Plot the cross point

x3 = np.linspace(6, 7, 1000)        # (6, 7) intersection range
y1_new = np.linspace(240, 50, 1000) # (6, 7) corresponding to (240, 50) in y1
y2_new = np.linspace(67, 88, 1000)  # (6, 7) corresponding to (67, 88) in y2

idx = np.argwhere(np.isclose(y1_new, y2_new, atol=0.1)).reshape(-1)
ax.plot(x3[idx], y2_new[idx], 'ro')

plt.show()
```

---

The end user would not be happy to input the cross range manually. Here is an improved version by looping over every two segments, but it might be a time consumer.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
y1 = [20,100,50,120,55,240,50,25]
x2 = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y2 = [25,35,14,67,88,44,120]

ax.plot(x1, y1, color='lightblue',linewidth=3)
ax.plot(x2, y2, color='darkgreen', marker='^')

# Get the common range, from `max(x1[0], x2[0])` to `min(x1[-1], x2[-1])`   
x_begin = max(x1[0], x2[0])     # 3
x_end = min(x1[-1], x2[-1])     # 8

points1 = [t for t in zip(x1, y1) if x_begin<=t[0]<=x_end]  # [(3, 50), (4, 120), (5, 55), (6, 240), (7, 50), (8, 25)]
points2 = [t for t in zip(x2, y2) if x_begin<=t[0]<=x_end]  # [(3, 25), (4, 35), (5, 14), (6, 67), (7, 88), (8, 44)]

idx = 0
nrof_points = len(points1)
while idx < nrof_points-1:
    # Iterate over two line segments
    y_min = min(points1[idx][1], points1[idx+1][1]) 
    y_max = max(points1[idx+1][1], points2[idx+1][1]) 

    x3 = np.linspace(points1[idx][0], points1[idx+1][0], 1000)      # e.g., (6, 7) intersection range
    y1_new = np.linspace(points1[idx][1], points1[idx+1][1], 1000)  # e.g., (6, 7) corresponding to (240, 50) in y1
    y2_new = np.linspace(points2[idx][1], points2[idx+1][1], 1000)  # e.g., (6, 7) corresponding to (67, 88) in y2

    tmp_idx = np.argwhere(np.isclose(y1_new, y2_new, atol=0.1)).reshape(-1)
    if tmp_idx:
        ax.plot(x3[tmp_idx], y2_new[tmp_idx], 'ro')                 # Plot the cross point

    idx += 1

plt.show()
```

Comment: I am animating the graph in the actual scenario, and I don't think the end user would like providing the inputs (6,7), so as to get the answer- Thanks

Comment: @basum, I agree. That's why I said it is an ugly solution.

Comment: @basum, I added an improved version to my answer without inputting the cross range manually.

Answer (score 1):

I've expanded @SparkAndShine's solution to work with 3D data, as well as did some performance enhancements using a KD-tree. Full solution is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51145981/4212158

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
from scipy import interpolate

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], projection='3d')
ax.axis('off')

def upsample_coords(coord_list):
    # s is smoothness, set to zero
    # k is degree of the spline. setting to 1 for linear spline
    tck, u = interpolate.splprep(coord_list, k=1, s=0.0)
    upsampled_coords = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 100), tck)
    return upsampled_coords

# target line
x_targ = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
y_targ = [20, 100, 50, 120, 55, 240, 50, 25]
z_targ = [20, 100, 50, 120, 55, 240, 50, 25]
targ_upsampled = upsample_coords([x_targ, y_targ, z_targ])
targ_coords = np.column_stack(targ_upsampled)

# KD-tree for nearest neighbor search
targ_kdtree = cKDTree(targ_coords)

# line two
x2 = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y2 = [25,35,14,67,88,44,120]
z2 = [25,35,14,67,88,44,120]
l2_upsampled = upsample_coords([x2, y2, z2])
l2_coords = np.column_stack(l2_upsampled)

# plot both lines
ax.plot(x_targ, y_targ, z_targ, color='black', linewidth=0.5)
ax.plot(x2, y2, z2, color='darkgreen', linewidth=0.5)

# find intersections
for i in range(len(l2_coords)):
    if i == 0:  # skip first, there is no previous point
        continue

    distance, close_index = targ_kdtree.query(l2_coords[i], distance_upper_bound=.5)

    # strangely, points infinitely far away are somehow within the upper bound
    if np.isinf(distance):
        continue

    # plot ground truth that was activated
    _x, _y, _z = targ_kdtree.data[close_index]
    ax.scatter(_x, _y, _z, 'gx')
    _x2, _y2, _z2 = l2_coords[i]
    ax.scatter(_x2, _y2, _z2, 'rx')  # Plot the cross point


plt.show()
```