# How to find intersection points between two colums in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to find the intersection points in two lists of numbers that do not necessarily  have any but the lines do intersect at some point

```py
lst0 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
lst1 = [2,4,1,4,1,5,7,8,3,2,4,7,8,2,1]
lst2 = [9,1,3,7,8,2,0,1,2,5,9,3,5,2,6]


data = {"index":lst0,
        "list1":lst1,
        "list2":lst2}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df.head(5))
```

the points of the first line are (1,2)(2,4)
the points of the second line are (1,9)(2,1)

the intersection point should be around (0.5,3)

does pandas have anything to do so, I tried [intersection](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) but I don't think it covers my goal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - matplotlib: find intersection of lineplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094374/python-matplotlib-find-intersection-of-lineplots)

Comment: How do you come up with the points? I don't quite understand how you get the point combinations from the two lists.

Comment: @moritz `lst0` is the x index and `lst1`, `lst2` are the y indexes that share the same x values

Comment: @Stef what if i am not allowed to use scipy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `lst1` and `lst2` share the same x values (`lst0`), you can do it with simple maths: just get the slope and offset for each line segment (`m` and `n` for `lst1` vs. `lst0`, and `k` and `l` for `lst2` vs `lst0`, respectively). By equaling the two segment equations you get the `x` coords of the intersections (`xs`) and then from `m` and `n` the `y` coords:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lst0 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
lst1 = [2,4,1,4,1,5,7,8,3,2,4,7,8,2,1]
lst2 = [9,1,3,7,8,2,0,1,2,5,9,3,5,2,6]
data = {"index":lst0,
        "list1":lst1,
        "list2":lst2}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x = df['index'].to_numpy()
y = df.list1.to_numpy()
z = df.list2.to_numpy()

# slopes and offsets lst1 vs lst0
m = np.diff(y)/np.diff(x)
n = y[1:] - m * x[1:]

# slopes and offsets lst2 vs lst0
k = np.diff(z)/np.diff(x)
l = z[1:] - k * x[1:]

# intersections
with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    xs = (n - l) / (k - m)
    ys = m * xs + n

# only take intersections that lie in the respective segment
mask = (xs >= x[:-1]) & (xs <= x[1:])
intersections = np.unique(np.row_stack((xs[mask], ys[mask])), axis=1)

# display result
ax = df.set_index('index').plot(legend=False)
ax.plot(intersections[0], intersections[1], 'ro')
```

[image]

Comment: what if the x axis was a datetime value with `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` format, how can i perform the same calculation without converting it into an epoch number